# How to use globally registered components in JSX/TSX without importing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, tsx

`VButton` has been globally registered and can be used in SFC `<template>` directly, how can I use it without manually importing in JSX/TSX?

```
// globally register `VButton`
Vue.createApp({...}).component('VButton', {...})
```

```
//  have to import this, is there a way to
// use `VButton` without importing, since it's
// already registered globally.
import VButton from '@/components/VButton.vue'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    return () => <VButton>Click Me</VButton>
  },
})
```

Comment: This isn't how JSX works. Check how React components are written. `VButton` is a variable like any other and needs to either be imported or defined globally on `window` in order to be accessed. Global components may be accessible on Vue instance but doing this will make the code more fragile, and certainly isn't friendly to TSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't expect using `VButton` directly works out of the box after global registration.

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    //            just use it
    return () => <VButton>Click Me</VButton>
  },
})
```

Comment: Except you're importing VButton somewhere else (that's not included in your snippet) this will (and does) not work as VButton is an undefined variable and an error (especially if you're using typescript) occurs cos the variable is unrecognized.

Answer (score 1):

Vue borrows `render` function and JSX from React, and the code is supposed to be written the same way, by explicitly importing components that are used in a component. Components are variables, in order to be accessed as `VButton` they need to be either imported or be declared as global variables on `window`.

Registered global components can be accessed on global Vue instance in Vue 2:

```
const VButton = Vue.options.components.VButton;
```

Or from component instance in Vue 3:

```
const instance = getCurrentInstance();
const VButton = instance.appContext.components.VButton;
```

These ways aren't documented.

The official way in Vue 3 is to use `resolveComponent`:

```
const VButton = resolveComponent('VButton');
```

Neither of them will result in correctly typed component with TSX.

Comment: It occurred to me that [`resolveComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#resolvecomponent) does the job too, in this case, `const VButton = resolveComponent('VButton')`, could you add it as well?

Comment: I was aware of resolveComponent but didn't think of it. Good point, it's likely a more acceptable option than the second one.